# Good practice in time series tests with different start/end dates

Tags: time-series, exchange-rates

I am testing purchasing power parity on monthly data, in a sample of about 70 to 200 countries depending on which price index / currency pair is used. Would it be considered bad practice to use different start and end dates for each currency pair?

For example, suppose I run a plain-vanilla univariate real exchange rate unit root test on each of 70 currency pairs, each of which happens to have different start and end dates. Would it be considered bad practice to start in say 1959 and end in 2017 in a test conducted on one series and start in 1979 and end in 2023 in another, given that this is the date range you have and do not want to lose any data?